# Positive Definiteness of Band Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, positive-definite

Let $A$ be the $n \times n$ matrix:
$$ 
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 1\\
1 & a & 1\\
&1 & a &1\\
&&\ddots &\ddots & \ddots\\
&&&1 & a& 1\\
&&&&1&a
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Show that $A$ is positive definite for $a \ge 2$.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem so far?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I've thought about using Sylvester's Criterion but am not sure how to show that the principal determinants are all positive.

Comment: Presumably you don't want that last column: the bottom right entry is $a$.

Comment: It seems so numerically, however it is not a sufficient condition. It is positive definite when a = 1.9 and n = 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $2 |x_i x_{i+1}| \le x_i^2 + x_{i+1}^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but I don't follow how this relates to a matrix being positive definite?

Comment: $A$ is positive definite if $x^T A x > 0$ for all real $x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

These illustrate, for $a=2,$ how to use [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Statement_in_terms_of_eigenvalues). In order to get $a > 2$ we are just adding a positive multiple of the identity.

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Your matrix $A$ satisfies $$A = (n-1)^2 B + (a-2)I$$ where $B$ is the discrete Laplacian of dimension $n$. It is known that $B$ is symmetric positive definite. Hence, $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

Option 2: Gershgorin's circle theorem implies that $A$ is symmetric positive definite for all $a>2$. Gershgorin's theorem does not apply directly to the case of $a=2$ as it cannot eliminate $0$ as an eigenvalue.